# React/JS - How to pass additional parameters to onClick handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The scenario is simple - I have some spans that when I click on them I use the event "e" to track what element the user clicked on (I have many elements like this) so getting the "e.target" is pretty simple from onClick like this:

```
React.createElement('span', {
    onClick: this._toggleIcons
}, span);

_toggleIcons: function(e){
    $(e.target).toggleClass("show");
},
```

So far so good.

---

However now I need to pass some additional parameters to the event "e" but I don't know how to do that. I cannot see whether this is possible/impossible.

```
React.createElement('span', {
    onClick: this._toggleRemoveOption( ?params? )
}, span2);

_toggleRemoveOption: function(e, param1, param2){
    $(e.target).toggleClass("remove");

    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(param1);
    console.log(param2);
},
```

So my question is this - how to white my onClick event handler parameters so that I can use them (param1, param2) and also have access to "e.target"?

Thank you

Comment: There is no need to add tag-words like _solved_, _resolved_, etc. to the question title, StackOverflow has a built-in way to communicate that a question has an accepted answer. :)

Comment: I see. Ok, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new function (es5ify way)

```
React.createElement('span', {
    onClick: (function(_this){
      return function(e) {
        _this._toggleRemoveOption(e, 'param1', 'param2')
      }
    }(this))

}, span2);
```

Or

```
React.createElement('span', {
    onClick: function(e) {
        this._toggleRemoveOption(e, 'param1', 'param2')
    }.bind(this)

}, span2);
```

Comment: Wow. :O This works like a Charm!!! Thank you my friend! I love you and stackoverflow! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use bind:

```
React.createElement('span', {
        onClick: this._toggleRemoveOption.bind(null, param1, param2)
    }, span2);


    _toggleRemoveOption: function(param1, param2, e){
        $(e.target).toggleClass("remove");

        console.log(e.target);
        console.log(param1);
        console.log(param2);
    },
```

Comment: This answer also works perfectly! Thank you very much!